# Image of open set through linear map

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f$ is a linear map between vector spaces, and whenever $U$ is an open set containing $0$, then $f(0)$ is an interior point of $f(U)$. Can we deduce that any open set containing $0$ has an open image by $f$? How?

Comment: What does it mean for an arbitrary subset of a vector space to be open?

Comment: I had "normed vector spaces" in mind, for the topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be **topological** vector spaces and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a linear function that takes zero neighbourhoods of $X$ into zero neighborhoods of $Y$.

**Lemma**: $f$ maps open sets in $X$ into open sets in $Y$.

*Proof*: Suppose that $N\subseteq X$ is an open set. Pick any $x\in N$. We will show that $f(x)$ is an interior point of $f(N)$. Notice that $N-x$ is a zero neighborhood. Thus, $f(N-x)$ is a zero neighborhood. This implies that $f(N-x)+f(x)$ is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$. Because $f$ is linear $f(N-x)+f(x)= f(N)$. 
We conclude that $f(x)$ is an interior point of $f(N)$. Because $x\in N$ was an arbitrary choice we conclude that $f(N)$ is open. QED